# Why is NSLocalizedString generating 'Use of undeclared type' in the same file?

Tags: swift, xcode, nslocalizedstring

**I am using Xcode 10.3 and Swift 5**

I have a long struct with my Localizable Strings as follows:

```
import Foundation
struct Strings {
    static let string1 = NSLocalizedString("String 1", comment:"")
    ....
}
```

I wanted to get rid of all the repetitive text (, comment:"" at the end of each struct item) so I wrote a one line extension as follows, in the same file, but I get the `'Use of undeclared type'` error in the extension

```
import Foundation
extension NSLocalizedString {  // 'Use of undeclared type'
}     
struct Strings {
    static let string1 = NSLocalizedString("String 1", comment:"")
    ...
}
```

I tried to do the same with a `String` extension and a new class `LString`, and creating a `class` method that returns the `NSLocalizedString` object, with the same result

Why is `NSLocalizedString` recognized inside the `struct` but not in the extension?. (They are in the same file)

Am I missing something?

Comment: `NSLocalizedString` is a function, not a type

Comment: Thx @dan for the clarification.... Basic stuff...    I will review my approach...  thx

Comment: Don't use `static` with NSLocalizedString. If you switch languages while the app is open, the string will not update due to the static declaration.

Comment: @dan. If you put this in an answer I will be happy to select it as the valid one